# How to insert Database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use an SQLite Database only to read Data. What is in there won't be ever changed, so the content should be already there when the user launches the app. Is there a better way to do this than to make a check in the onCreate method if the user has launched the app before and if not write the Database? That would require me to do a lot of copy-pasting and editing, end chaning would be messy. Instead, I hoped there was a way I could convert my Access or Excel files into an SQLite database that I just place wherever it reads from. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Use [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: This tells me how to use it, but not how to create it, but thanks-

Comment: Creating it has little to do with Android. I don't know if there is an existing Access/Excel-to-SQLite tool, but you could put together some script on Windows to handle that. For example, [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android) has a full-text-search index using SQLite. So, when I publish a book update (as I just did), I generate a SQLite database from the book contents, using a little Ruby script.